# Unable to connect Kobiton Android device to Appium script

Tags: appium, android-testing, appium-android, kobiton

I am trying to connect my Appium script to Kobiton as I would like to test it however I am getting some errors which I do not understand why.

The test simply prints "Application running" if the connection is established

I have copy and pasted the dependencies that was given to me in the "Automation settings" on Kobiton

Please note : I have changed the personal information such as ids etc just to show in this question

My code:

```
public class webUITests {

static AppiumDriver driver;

public static void main(String[] args){

    try{
        openWebui();
    }
    catch (Exception exp){
        System.out.println(exp.getCause());
        System.out.println(exp.getMessage());
        exp.printStackTrace();
    }


}

public static void openWebui() throws MalformedURLException {
    //String kobitonServerUrl = "https://j.camp:58ea1eeff30-b5ca-42fc-b451-88a54746427e@api.kobiton.com/wd/hub";
    DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
    capabilities.setCapability("sessionName", "Automation test session");
    capabilities.setCapability("sessionDescription", "");
    capabilities.setCapability("deviceOrientation", "portrait");
    capabilities.setCapability("captureScreenshots", false);
    capabilities.setCapability("app", "kobiton-store:v489586");
    capabilities.setCapability("groupId", 1670); // Group: Testers
    capabilities.setCapability("deviceGroup", "KOBITON");
    capabilities.setCapability("udid", "08111vvxJEC224197");
    URL url = new URL("https://j.camp:58ea1eeff30-b5ca-42fc-b451-88a54746427e@api.kobiton.com/wd/hub");
    driver = new AppiumDriver(url,capabilities);
    System.out.println(("Application Starting...."));
}
```

}

Error messages:

```
org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Could not start a new session. Response code 500. Message: Internal error: failed to launch/book device. ErrorID: MH-400


Driver info: io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver
Command: [null, newSession {capabilities=[{appium:app=kobiton-store:v489586, 
appium:captureScreenshots=false, appium:deviceGroup=KOBITON, 
appium:deviceOrientation=portrait, appium:groupId=1670, appium:sessionDescription=, 
appium:sessionName=Automation test session, appium:udid=08111vvxJEC224197}], 
desiredCapabilities=Capabilities {app: kobiton-store:v489586, captureScreenshots: false, 
deviceGroup: KOBITON, deviceOrientation: portrait, groupId: 1670, sessionDescription: , 
sessionName: Automation test session, udid: 08111vvxJEC224197}}]
Capabilities {}
at 
org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:144)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumProtocolHandshake.createSession(AppiumProtocolHandshake.java:126)
at io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumProtocolHandshake.createSession(AppiumProtocolHandshake.java:102)
at io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor.createSession(AppiumCommandExecutor.java:155)
at io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor.execute(AppiumCommandExecutor.java:189)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:547)
at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.startSession(AppiumDriver.java:229)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:157)
at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.<init>(AppiumDriver.java:80)
at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.<init>(AppiumDriver.java:92)
at webuitests.webUITests.openWebui(webUITests.java:41)
at webuitests.webUITests.main(webUITests.java:18)
```

Answer (score 0):

To connect a kobiton device to appium , you DO NOT start the kobiton device. You simply paste the capabilities from the Kobiton device settings into your code and then run your code